# css: simulate a "min-top" property

Tags: html, css, alignment, margin

I have the following div:

```
#leftmenu{
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -65x;
height: 130px;
}
```

This div is placed vertically centered on the page and it is fixed, the webpage is very tall but the div is always visible in the center of the screen. With these properties, if I resize the window the menu moves because it has to stay at 50% of the current window size. What I want is:
1) when I load the page, depending on the screen resolution, the div must place 50% top (ok with my code)
2) if I resize the window, it must stay fixed.
I hoped there was a property like "min-top" or something like this to force the top level, but it doesn't exist.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

> 1) when I load the page, depending on the screen resolution, the div must place 50% top (ok with my code)

**Suggestion:** For (**depending on screen resolution**) that you should have media queries, its a css which would let you have specific propeties for your divs depending on the screen resolution. Suppose you have a default `960px` width, and when the screens gets `330px` you can use this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 330px) {
  /*change the div position or what so ever. 
  This will work like javascript but is better!*/
}
```

Then you will see the change in the div's position or its style of width and bla bla.

> 2) if I resize the window, it must stay fixed. I hoped there was a property like "min-top" or something like this to force the top level, but it doesn't exist.

Yes, there is no code that would do what you want to without writing a thing. For this you must write these lines.

1. For `stay fixed`?

   write this:

   `div {

    position: fixed;

    }`

   It should go inside the `media query`. Then when you will resize, it will get the second style that would go for the second screen!
2. Force to top-level? You can use this:

   `div {

    position: absolute;

    top: 0;

    }`

The `top: 0;` would make sure that it should have `margin-top: 0;`. You can use this code.

**Edit:**

You posted this in the comment:

> I've googled on media query. I think it is not the solution to my problem. Different resolution are not a problem, with the actual css with every resolution the div is placed 50% top. The problem is when (with all resolutions) I resize the browser window. I'd like that resizing the window the menu doesn't move up or down

For this, the issue is almost totally opposite! The issue is the percentage, when you are resizing the div, you are making the div shorter or larger! Which is changing its position.

You can use this for the `body` tag.

```
body {
min-width: 900px;
max-width: 900px;
}
```

This way, it will always just stay the `900px`, no matter you resize it shorted or larger. It will not change or will never change its width untill you change it using media-query! I hope I answer your question now.

Comment: Mmm, I think it is not the solution for my purpose. The point 1) is already running fine.

Comment: hehe no no, you got it wrong brother! I gave a suggestion for the word `depending on screen resolution`.

Comment: I said that to explain that with ALL resolution I want to obtain the requested behaviour, while the 50% top align already runs well with my css.

Comment: If 50% align to the top words, then guess what? There is some other css property to deal with the other type! Have you checked it all? Or I mean can you post the code please?

Comment: Hey maurice, check the answer now!

Answer (score 0):

Is position relative to the browser window.

Use `position: absolute;` to position relative to the `document`.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't understood your advice. How can I make it relative to the document?

Comment: I meant about the content

Comment: This is Not the answer